# RegExp for dates Extjs 3.4

Tags: regex, date, search, extjs, extjs3

I have problem to make regExp for search panel

```
&& (item.get('prodAddDate') >= dateStartValue.format("Y-m-d"))
&& (item.get('prodAddDate') <= dateEndValue.format("Y-m-d"));
```

I'm not sure if this is task for refExp but don't have any other idea

Problem is that when I'm don't fill field with date I can't filtr data with other conditions

I was trying something like this but don't working

```
    && ((item.get('prodAddDate') >= dateStartValue.format("Y-m-d")) || (new RegExp(dateStartValue)).test(item.get('prodAddDate'))) &&
 ((item.get('prodAddDate') <= dateEndValue.format("Y-m-d")) || (new RegExp(dateEndValue)).test(item.get('prodAddDate')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but here are some pieces of information that I hope can help you to solve your problem.

### Comparison operators priority

The `&&` operator has priority over `||`, which means that:

```
A || B && C || D
```

Is equivalent to:

```
A || (B && C) || D
```

Not to:

```
(A || B) && (C || D)
```

### Date comparison

You can compare `Date` objects directly:

```
// example data
var d1 = new Date('2012-12-12'),
    d2 = new Date('2012-12-12'),
    d3 = new Date('2013-01-01');
```

And get the result you expect with `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`:

```
// logical results
d1 < d3 // true
d1 < d2 // false
d2 > d3 // false
d1 <= d2 // true
d1 => d2 // true
```

But not with equality comparison `==`:

```
d1 == d2 // false
// yet...
d1 <= d2 && d1 => d2 // true
```

Conclusion: to test if one date is before or after another one, direct comparison is OK. But, in order to test if two dates are identical, use string comparisons:

```
// is this the same day?
d1.format('Y-m-d') === d2.format('Y-m-d') // true

// is this the same day and hour?
d1.format('Y-m-d H:i:s') === d2.format('Y-m-d H:i:s') // true
```

### Ext.isEmpty()

[`Ext.isEmpty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-isEmpty) returns `true` for: `null`, `undefined` and empty strings `''` **only**.

```
Ext.isEmpty(null) // true
Ext.isEmpty(undefined) // true
Ext.isEmpty('') // true

Ext.isEmpty(' ') // false
Ext.isEmpty(false) // false
// etc.
```

That may be useful to address your empty field case:

```
...
&& (Ext.isEmpty(item.get('prodAddDate') || item.get('prodAddDate') >= dateStartValue)
&& (Ext.isEmpty(item.get('prodAddDate') || item.get('prodAddDate') <= dateEndValue)
```

### Finally

What's this obsession about regex? They're useful for complex string testing/extracting, but that's all. You should probably forget about them for a while, dude ;p

Comment: Thanks for nice piece of knowledge mate  :) Everything working